# Should I drop Nan before before creating a scatter plot and computing the correlation matrix?

Tags: data-cleaning, correlation

I have some NaN values in my data and I cannot replace it with median or something else.

Now I have to check out the correlation, using scatter plot and Pearson correlation.

**Should I drop these NaNs or there is no difference?** Actually, I see the difference, but a very, very small difference. What is the best solution here?

Comment: Is the very, very small difference important? It might depend on how the specific pearson correlation function you're using deals with NaNs

Answer (score 0):

Yes - drop NaNs. Even if the Pearson correlation implementation you are using can return a number, what does that number mean? How could you interpret that number?